# Does OpenEBS support Nomad as orchestration platform?

Tags: orchestration, nomad, openebs

I'm curious whether OpenEBS supports Nomad as orchestration platform? I haven't found any information in github repo except these few jobspecs https://github.com/openebs/elves/tree/master/nomad

Answer (score 2):

OpenEBS is currently tightly integrated w/ K8s and the earlier support for nomad has been deprecated.

Comment: "Tight" in what way? It's just running a container, right? Or does it actually depend on the k8s api-server / dns service names?